# Cancelar alterações AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código, para desfazer as alterações:

```
    $pageContent = content;
    $scope.page = $pageContent.page;
    var pageBackup = $pageContent.page;

    $scope.cancelChanges = function() {
        $scope.page = pageBackup;
        $scope.$apply;
    };
```

Mas quando mudo alguma coisa em `$scope.page` muda também no `pageBackup`. Alguém poderia me explicar o motivo disso ocorrer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está apenas criando uma nova referência para o objeto, assim, qualquer mudança no original reflete na referência.

A saída é **copiar** o objeto original, e recuperar o backup desta cópia.

```
$pageContent = content;
$scope.page = $pageContent.page;

$scope.backup = {};
angular.copy( $scope.page, $scope.backup );
// Ou, se preferir:
// $scope.backup = angular.copy( $scope.page );

$scope.cancelChanges = function() {
    angular.copy( $scope.backup, $scope.page );
    $scope.$apply;
};
```

Comment: consegui utulizando o `angular.copy` mesmo XD valeu